# Is the rediscovery of a result of a published paper from a different source plagiarism?

Tags: plagiarism

Is the rediscovery of a mathematical formula using a different method to the result of a different paper than the one that published the formula earlier considerable as plagiarism or unethical in some way?

Comment: Does the rediscover know about the previous method? Do they cite it and recognize it's existence?

Comment: Yes. The result was proven using modular arithmetic in the published paper while the rediscovery was derived using progressions and it was cited.

Comment: The term "rediscovery" would imply, as far as my understanding goes, that the person who "rediscovered" a result didn't actually know it already from the earlier paper. In your posting this is unclear. It seems you are just asking about giving a different proof for an already known result.

Comment: A result was given in a paper and it was extended by the author and result of this extension turned out be a result of a published paper. The method used in the extension is distinct from the method used in the published paper. 

Will the presentation of the extension as a result of its own be considered as plagiarism?

Comment: Okay, so in what way are the author(s) of the rediscovery taking credit for the ideas of others as if they are their own without properly attributing them to the original source (plagiarism)?

Comment: The published paper is present in the references but the published result which the author rediscovered using a different method wasn't mentioned to already exist in that published paper.

Comment: They cite that paper without acknowledging it also shows the same thing they show? What do they cite it for?

Comment: It was cited for a different result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, rediscovery isn't plagiarism. It is fairly common. Using a different methodology to arrive at a known result isn't plagiarism and is valued, especially in some fields like math.

Plagiarism is wrongly attributing ideas to yourself. If the result is known and one cites that original source, then providing a different way to arrive at it is a valued part of academic research.

The key, however, is citation when the source is known.

Some things get rediscovered by people who don't actually know that the result is known and try to publish without citation, since they don't know any such. That isn't plagiarism either. Plagiarism requires knowledge of the source but not citing it. It might "look like" plagiarism to a more knowledgeable observer but isn't, technically. To be published, such things, if noticed, would probably require a rewrite to give a fuller context than what was originally presented.

And, some things, once known, are actually lost and then rediscovered. That is less likely in the modern, connected, age, of course.

Comment: So if a result was already found and published and presented again by author using the very same method as his/her own, it qualifies as plagiarism but if the result was reached through a different method and by extending a result outside of the published paper, it does not?

Comment: You miss the point, I think. Plagiarism is misappropriation. And, just as important, plagiarism is about ideas. If you _knowingly_ claim that the ideas of others are your own then it is plagiarism. If you don't know then it isn't (though you probably should have known). If you cite the original then it isn't. If you repeat old work exactly, then it isn't likely publishable. It isn't being new that avoids plagiarism, it is citation of what is known that avoids it. If I claim to have discovered the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus it is plagiarism. If I cite, but provide a new proof it is fine.